# Unable to Decrypt using TripleDES in .NET encrypted in Java

Tags: c#, java, 3des

We have a Java client that sending us some encrypted data 
1. A random string is encrypted using RSA and public key we provided them offline.
2. using the key generated in step1 they encrypt the data using alg_tripleDES_CBC = http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc

I was able to decrypt the key from 1st step like this ... which is working.

```
public static string DecryptKey(string encryptedKey)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\test.pfx", "test");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKeyProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

        string decryptedKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privateKeyProvider.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedKey), false));

        return decryptedKey;

    }
```

And I have this code to decrypt the data using the key generated from 1st step.

```
 public static string DecryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);

        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
            Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }

        return UTF8.GetString(Results);
    }
```

And the second step fails with this exception.

```
   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._DecryptData(SafeKeyHandle hKey, Byte[] data, Int32 ib, Int32 cb, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode PaddingMode, Boolean fDone)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoAPITransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at ConsoleApplication3.Program.DecryptString(String Message, String Passphrase) in C:\Documents and Settings\rjaladi\Desktop\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:line 66
   at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\rjaladi\Desktop\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:line 22
```

What is that I need to check with our client? I know that there is something wrong with the parameters we are passing to TDES. Any help?

EDIT: Corresponding Java code that encrypts the message.

```
public String encryptText(String plainText) throws Exception{

  byte[] plaintext = plainText.getBytes();
  byte[] tdesKeyData = key;
  byte[] myIV = initializationVector;

  Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance(""DESede/CBC/NoPadding"");
  SecretKeySpec    myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
  IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(myIV);
     c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
  byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(plaintext);
  sun.misc.BASE64Encoder obj64=new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
  return obj64.encode(cipherText);
 }
```

Comment: It's failing on TransformFinalBlock, suggesting that your data length is wrong.

Comment: What have you done to debug the parameter, have you verified they are the same values, based on the fact its throwing an exception I would say you have done nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is being thrown in `_DecryptData(...)` which I notice includes a `PaddingMode` parameter.  Padding at the end of that last block will be checked and an error thrown if incorrect padding is found.  I suggest that you check with whoever is sending the data to see what padding mode they are using.  You will need to use the same padding mode when decrypting.

As @klartrex says, you should not use ECB mode, it leaks information; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) for a (literal) illustration.  Use either CBC or CTR mode instead if you can persuade the other end to do so.

Comment: I tried CBC mode too, that is not working. I added the corresponding java code that encrypts the message.

Comment: Actually I have changed padding mode to none as thejava code I just received specified no padding. And chipermode to cbc.. now there is no exeception. But it gives garbage, which I think maybe the encoding is not right.

Comment: @Broken Link: CBC mode needs an IV, a wrong IV will give garbage for the first block.  You **must** use the same key, mode, padding and IV (if used) as the sender.  If all of the message is junk then check the key, byte by byte so it matches exactly.

Comment: you are just Awesome. I finally figured that out. But there is a problem. Let's say on Java side they are using a empty IV and on my side I have to initialize it with some 8 bit code(does't matter what it is?) Lets say the key was "abcdefghijklmnop1234567890" I was using "abcdefgh" to initialize IV (i tried all possibilities from the key to initialize the IV) and i was able to decrypt except the first 8 characters!! Do you know why that could be?

Comment: @Broken Link: The wrong IV in CBC mode will mess up the first block (8 chars in DES), but leave the rest of the message OK.  Explicitly set the IV to the correct value, which may be `{0x00, 0x00 ... 0x00}`.

Comment: you are absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this fails:

```
TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
```

You should use CBC ciphermode if you used CBC to encrypt the Java. And its not recommended to use ECB anyways, because it has some security flaws.

Comment: I tried with CBC too.. I was able to get the java code that encrypts this message. If this helps.

Comment: Actually I have changed padding mode to none as thejava code I just received specified no padding. And chipermode to cbc.. now there is no exeception. But it gives garbage, which I think maybe the encoding is not right.